# How to load UI on left side of spreadsheet window

Tags: google-apps-script

how to set the Spreadsheet UI window appears on left side of spreadsheet like "Named and Protectd Range..." did?

Comment: Could you give us a little more information?  What exactly are you trying to do?  What have you tried?  Could you show us some of the code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The element you are describing is called the Sidebar, and it appears on the left in languages that read right-to-left, and on the right in others.

You don't yet have the ability to display Sidebar elements in Sheets. See [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) for details of what you can do.

You do now have the ability to do this in Documents, though. See [Custom Menus and User Interfaces in Extending Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs?hl=en#custom_menus_and_user_interfaces), especially [`showSidebar()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showSidebar%28Object%29), for more about that.